Probability vs Frequency
By observed freuency, one hits the target 90 times out of 100 times so we then conclude P(hit) = 0.9. Then, the probi one can hit 90 times out of 100 times = 100C90 • 0.9^90 • 0.1^10 = 0.1319, which is far less than 0.9. So actually how should we understand P(hit) = 0.9 this statement. From frequency, seems we are saying 90% of the times one will hit, so why not P(90 hit out of 100 hit) simply = 0.9? (I know it is wrong but I can't give a good explanation to this) Also, if not using frequency approach, then P(hit) = 0.9 is it just we can say someone is "quite/very accurate" only? Thanks for all your comments!!

$p=0.9$ derived thus is really an estimate worked backwards from $90$ hits in $100$ shots. As you can see, If we plug in $p=0.9$  in the formula for expected value, of the number of hits in $100$ shots,it will come to $90$
$$\sum_{k=o}^{100}k\cdot{\binom{100}k}\cdot p^k\cdot (1-p)^{100-k} \;= 90$$

For a single series of 100 shots the chance of getting exactly 90 hits is indeed relatively low. The chance of getting approximately 90 hits is a lot higher, depending on how approximate you are prepared to be. If you do many series of 100 shots the average number of hits per series is very likely to be close to 90.

Extending the comment of peter, consider the probability that the number of hits will be between 85 and 94, inclusive.
